# I can't get Postgres configured correctly

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, init.d

I have spent quite a bit of time wrestling with this postgresql update, but I just can't quite get it configured correctly. I recently upgraded from 9.0 to 9.1, and I can't get Postgres 9.1 configured correctly.

I wanted it to start on start up, so I went and found the postgres file in etc/init.d and replaced it with the script that came with the source files (the linux script found in `/contrib/start-scripts`).

I only changed some of the stuff as follows:

```
# Installation prefix
prefix="/usr/local/pgsql"

# Data directory
PGDATA="/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main"

# Who to run the postmaster as, usually "postgres".  (NOT "root")
PGUSER=postgres

# Where to keep a log file
PGLOG="/var/log/postgresql/9.1"
```

Then I installed and ran `chkconfig --add postgresql`. From what I could see, the rhN directories seemed to have been updated. But, unfortunately, Postgresqk didn't work, it does not start up, or at least, I don't think it starts up. Did I miss a step?

Also, when I run `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql` , the error says:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Whereas running the old server's psql command when it's not running gives:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What is that domain socket directory, and do I need to change it?

So, how do I get it to start up, if it helps, I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Lastly, I know it's bad etiquette to ask multiple questions, but I figured it would be rude to make another question for a small question like this: I also want to make it so that if I enter a postgres command (e.g. psql) into the terminal, it should run the new postgres command, not the old one like it does now. Where do I change this?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I installed and ran `chkconfig --add` postgresql

You need also turn on it:

```
chkconfig postgresql on
```

> Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Did you start the `postgresql`?

```
$ ps -ef | grep postgre
```

> What is that domain socket directory, and do I need to change it?

It contains the Unix domain socket which server is to listen for connections from the clients. You don't need to change (it can be done with `unix_socket_directory`).

---

> Now, the problem is that, I still need to write out the full location
>   of the directory when running a command. Hmm, how do I fix this.

Add it to the `$PATH` environment variable by inserting/appending the belows line to `~/.profile` in your `$HOME`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql/bin
```

Make this take effect with:

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

or:

```
$ . ~/.profile
```

You can also add to `/etc/profile` for global usage.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I didn't know you had to turn it on, I tried turning it on, but it didn't work, though it did give me these warnings: `insserv: warning: script 'K02postgresql' missing LSB tags and overrides`. Is the warning responsible for not making it work as well?

Comment: Why not use [sysv-rc-conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/sysv-rc-conf.8.html) instead of installing `chkconfig` on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yup, I went ahead and used sysv-rc-conf,I don't know if I needed to use it or not, but I figured out some problems in the script thanks to it, like for example, not defining a name for the log. So, now it works! Now, the problem is that, I still need to write out the full location of the directory when running a command. Hmm, how do I fix this.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I managed to add the location to the `$PATH` variable, but, the old ones are still used, and this is because those files still exist in `/usr/bin`. So, I need to either delete or replace them, and as such, just one small question remains. Is it a better practice to place the postgres programs in `/usr/bin` (by replacing the old ones) or leave them in the install directory and simply delete the old ones? Thanks for everything.

Comment: You can remove the old version if you don't want to use it anymore.